# Recyclerview and adapter doesn’t show

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M8sKwoVjqU0
i watched this video and i have done evertyhing same with.But there is a problem i guess myadapter class doesn't work because when i click button it comes just white screen as you see on the picture. i couldn't figure out where is the fault when i check the log no problem. but i just wanna take data from firebase to textview. but i can't get any result also at least it must see there just textview which is have text firstname but i can't see on my activity.i might be don't know the true page to will  show

---this my myadapter.class----

```
public class Myadapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Myadapter.MyViewHolder> {
Context context;
ArrayList<User> list ;
public Myadapter(Context context, ArrayList<User> list) {
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
}
@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item,parent,false);

    return new MyViewHolder(v) ;
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {


 User user =list.get(position);
   holder.textView.setText(user.getTitle());
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
  return  list.size();
    }
    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
TextView textView, TextView;
    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtview);
        textView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    }
}
```

---this my userlist.class---

```
public class userlist extends AppCompatActivity {
RecyclerView recyclerView;
        DatabaseReference database;
        Myadapter myadapter;
        ArrayList<User>list;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_userlist);
    recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.userlist);
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
list = new ArrayList<>();
myadapter = new Myadapter(this,list);
recyclerView.setAdapter(myadapter);
database.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for ( DataSnapshot dataSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()){
            User user=dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
list.add(user);
        }
        myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

---this my mainactivity.class---

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,userlist.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();}
});
    }
}
```

```js
{
  "users" : {
    "value1" : {
      "title" : "reachthis"
    }
  }
}
```

````
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".userlist">


---activity_userlist---
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/userlist"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="729dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>```

---item.xml---

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardElevation="8dp"
    
        >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">   </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    >
    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="first name"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="26sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"></TextView><TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="first name"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"
    
            ></TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
    
    
    
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
````

Comment: Have you tried to run the code without `recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);`? Does it work that way?

Comment: Yes i tried nothing change